# Is this an Apache Poi bug in java?

Tags: apache-poi

When I took out all the data in row #2, I noticed that my columns C, E, F were missing.
As follows:

- My excel file is a new file, I only enter data for columns A, B, D, G, H and columns C, E, F. I don't touch (don't click or touch the cell)

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuOR0.png)

- Then i use the following function to get the data from the columns of a row

  Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
- At this point, I noticed that the data of my columns C, E, F was lost. Specifically, in the row, only columns A, B, D, G, H and their respective data are displayed.
- As the picture above, if I color the data row to white or any color or the columns C, E, F I click on (don't write data in the column). Then I re-read the file, now the row receives enough data from all columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. with columns C, E, F, the data is empty.
- What do I do when sheet.getRow() doesn't lose columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Excel sheet only those rows and cells that not are completely unused are stored. A row is stored if at least one cell needs to be stored in that row. A cell needs to be stored if it has a cell value or has a special cell style (using data formatting, font formatting, interior formatting...). All other possible rows and/or cells are not stored.

So what you observed is not a bug in Apache POI but shows how Excel uses it's storage for rows and cells in sheets. Storing all possible cells would be a horrible waste of storage.

For not stored rows, `Sheet.getRow` return `null`. For not stored cells, `Row.getCell` return `null`. Not stored rows as well as not stored cells are not reachable using iterators.

So, if the need is to iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells, then the iterators are not usable. See [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) -> **Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells**.

Sample code provided there:

```java
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(15, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());
for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // This whole row is empty
      // Handle it as needed
      continue;
   }
   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);
   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```

As you see, you need to know needed first row and needed last row as well as needed column count. The sample code always starts om column 0 (A). Maybe you also know the first needed column to start there. And you need to null-check the row as well as the cell you got.